# OutOfLangMemoryError caused by Apache Axis2

Tags: java, apache-axis, out-of-memory

I asked this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706837/problems-caused-by-axis2-java-web-service-client-after-a-timeout) but got no response - maybe it was too long - so i'm rephrasing the question:
After about 3 days from starting an application that uses Apache Axis2 v.1.5.4, **OutOfLangMemoryError** start to occur (**heap size** = **2048 MB**) resulting either in degrading the application server (**WAS** v.7.0.0.7) performance or stopping the logical server (process still exists).

For some reasons, i have to put a **timer** = 1 second on the web service invocation process, in peak time, timeouts occur (either in establishment or reading).

Looking in the **javacores** and the **heapdumps** thrown by the server:
It seems that there are **hung** Axis2 threads:

```
"Axis2 Task" TID:0x00000000E4076200, j9thread_t:0x0000000122C2B100, state:P, prio=5.
at sun/misc/Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:173)
at java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:433)
at java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:334)
at java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:868)
at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
at java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
```

How to ensure that Axis2 threads are terminated, whether a response was returned or not i.e. exception occurred?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you point Visual VM 1.3.2, with all plugins installed, at your application.  It'll show you what's happening in your generational heap memory and all the threads that are started.  I can't give you the answer, but Visual VM will make the process more transparent.

Comment: Thanks duffymo, such a helpful tool, but my primary concern is to prevent the problem on development phase, by using Axis2 API, because it should be there, i tried using Stub, ServiceClient,Transport, and ConfigurationContext cleanup() methods, but got no luck. maybe i'm using the right API in a wrongly way.

Comment: Use Visual VM to point to your development machine and run the app locally.  I don't understand your point.

Comment: I used jca (http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jca), which is similar to Visual VM, to analyze the java cores/ heap dumps, it seems that problem is caused by Axi2.
My point is, i was asking whether there are some API that ensure that the all the resources are cleaned-up (memory, threads).
I found 29,459 threads with the state "parked" in the time of the problem.